# why the argument from filter operator is not taking a property that exist in the observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to filter an array that comes from an observable if the property "start" which is a date string match with another date string, but within the filter operator function the argument is not recognizing "start" as a valid property

I have read multiple examples and comparing to mine seems to be a very similar scenario

```
export class AuctionsService() {

private _auctions = new BehaviorSubject(
    [
      {
        idAuction: '1',
        start: '2019-07-18T15:30',
      },
      {
        idAuction: '2',
        start: '2019-07-18T15:30',
      },
      {
        idAuction: '3',
        start: '2019-07-18T15:30',
      },
      {
        idAuction: '4',
        start: '2019-07-19T15:30',
      },
    ]
  );
 get auctions() {
    return this._auctions.asObservable();
  }
}
```

On another file when I'm subscribing to this observable

```
    selectedDate = '2019-07-19T12:46';

  constructor(
    private auctionsService: AuctionsService,
  ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.auctionsService.auctions.pipe(filter(
          aucs => aucs.start.slice(0, 10) === this.selectedDate.slice(0, 10)
        )).subscribe(
          aucs => { this.auctions = aucs; }
        );
      }
```

Expected output should be:
      {
        idAuction: '4',
        start: '2019-07-19T15:30',
      },

but is not compiling it states .start is not a valid property of aucs

Comment: The thing is that `aucs` is an array, and I think you're expecting an item of that array instead.

Comment: Ok I just tried (aucs:any) => aucs.start.slice(0, 10) === this.selectedDate.slice(0, 10) and that removes the compilation error, but when it runs I still get aucs as undefined

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at auctions.page.ts:45
    at

Comment: What about instead of emitting an array you emit every item of the array and your subscription remains the same?

Comment: HI thanks for your feedback I'm actually learning so I think I jump from beginner to advance without properly know the basics, what you mean is I'm missusing filter in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dcg said, `aucs` as returned from the `this.auctionsService.auctions` observable is an array, but your code was treating it as if it was an element from an array. So you need to filter it as an array:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.auctionsService.auctions.pipe(
    map(
      aucs => aucs.filter(auc => auc.start === this.selectedDate;
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(aucs => {
    this.auctions = aucs;
  });
}
```